# HTML5 video not working on mobile phone

Tags: html, video

I'm trying to get a HTML5 video working on my web. On the desktop it works perfectly but it doesn't happen the same with my mobile phone. Instead, it appears the typical video-like image to show it's supposed to be a video there but wasn't loaded. I used [EasyHTML5Video](http://easyhtml5video.com/) to convert my video to several different formats and according to this SW, it should be compatible with lots of platforms... After the conversion, it gives you some code to use, which I modified to adapt the paths and the style.

My mobile phone uses Android 4.0.

**HTML**

```
<video id="video-background" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" poster="./images/starry_sky.jpg" loop="loop">
    <source src="./videos/time_lapse.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="./videos/time_lapse.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="./videos/time_lapse.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="./videos/time_lapse.mp4" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="./videos/flashfox.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="./videos/flashfox.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=true&controls=false&fullScreenEnabled=false&posterOnEnd=false&loop=true&poster=./images/starry_sky.jpg&src=time_lapse.m4v" />
        <embed src="./videos/flashfox.swf" flashVars="autoplay=true&controls=false&fullScreenEnabled=false&posterOnEnd=false&loop=true&poster=./images/starry_sky.jpg&src=./videos/time_lapse.m4v"  allowFullScreen="false" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
        <img alt="time_lapse" src="./images/starry_sky.jpg"/>
    </object>
</video>
```

**Edit**

I've tried to open it with the default browser. When I tried with Google Chrome the image inside the object tag was loaded but still not the video.

Comment: What browsers did you open your video in? Did you tried to open in other mobile browsers?

Comment: @phts I've edited the question to give that info you ask.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no reason to include both a `.m4v` and a `.mp4` file. Also, have you tried leaving out the Flash part altogether?

Comment: @herrbischoff I did. At the beguinning I tried just with webm and mp4 formats. Then I added ogg, m4v and flash, according to the code this EasyHTML5Video generated.

Comment: @Fernando: I have just added an answer that possibly solves this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) (rather old) post, you might need to add the following JavaScript code to make playback work on Android:

```
function myOnload() {
  var ua = navigator.userAgent;
  if (typeof ua != “undefined” && ua.match(/Android.* 2\.[0 – 2](\.[0 – 9]+)*[^.0 – 9]/i) !== null) {
    var vid = document.getElementById(“video”);
    vid.addEventListener(“click”, function() {
      vid.play();
    }, false);
  }
}
window.onload = myOnload;
```

Also, according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997200/html5-video-tag-failed-to-play-mp4-videos-in-phonegap-android-with-cordova-2-9), you may need to write the `video` tag like this:

```
<video class="video" poster="/assets/video/posters/example.jpg" controls width="768" height="432" preload="none">
  <source src="/assets/video/example.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="/assets/video/example.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but not solved it... The only thing that changes is that I didn't enable controls, because I'm looking for autoplay, and the width and height are different from the ones i was using :\